# Question on Federated Authentication using Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, wif

I am developing an Asp.Net MVC website using Windows Identity Foundation and STS website for authentication. it works fine as whenever a user tries to access a URL, it redirects to STS website if that session is not authenticated.

Now I want to add a page in the application which should be available without authenticating into the site. But I am unable to do that. I tried giving the following in web.config. Still it gets redirected to the STS website. Here i want to allow anonymous access to "Public" controller and all its actions.

```
<location path="Public">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

It will be great if somebody can guide me with the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mark your controllers with Autorize attribute?

Comment: Yes I am using Custom Authrozation attribute to secure the application. But it looks like the request is redirected to the STS before hitting this attribute.

Comment: as I know WIF intercept OnAuthenticateRequest and redirect it to STS. As I see you allow access to Public for all _authenticated_ users. You should turn off authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [sample app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff921345%28v=pandp.10%29). We ended up disabling the automatic redirect and controlling that ourselves.

More details on how it works [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eugeniop/wif-and-mvc-how-it-works).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I realize I'm about a year late with this answer, but I wanted to document it for future reference.

The asterisk (*) in the users attribute refers to all **authenticated** users. To allow anonymous or unauthenticated users, a question mark (?) should be used as shown below.

```
<location path="Public">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```